# Anyone know how to truncate this C++ to .txt file?

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char filename[] = "text.txt";
  std::fstream file;

  file.open(filename, ios::out | ios::trunc);
  file << "This text will now be inside of " << filename << std::endl;
  file.close();

  file.open(filename, ios::in);
  std::string line;
  std::getline(file, line);

  std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Is it clear enough, can the `char filename[] = text.txt` and the text.txt file shown be truncated somehow?
I can see the code above and the text.txt file in the image shown above and I don't know why it will not change. If the text.txt file is unreachable from the .cpp in the image.

Comment: Your program is looking for the file in its running directory.  Typically that is where the executable is located.

Comment: Check your working directory. It might be creating `text.txt` elsewhere. Or open the `txt` file again, maybe notepad doesn't update its contents when  changed on disk.

Comment: Right on guys, say you wouldn't happen to know how to refresh eh?

Comment: As already mentioned by @NathanOliver, you have to look at the executable folder not the folder contains your source code. Look here: `C:\Documents and Settings\Employee\My Documents\Downloads\upp\out\MyApps\MINGW.Debug.D...` (part after `D...` is not readable in your screenshot)

Comment: Perfect, right. Now is it possible to refresh or reactivate the truncation?

Comment: text.txt emptied //I can double click and see everythings gone so I type something and save, and open it again and the text.txt has something in it now? even when the wile loop is on?